# UITableview How to display images in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

[image]ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *table;
    NSArray *tableData;
}
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    table.delegate = self;
    table.dataSource = self;

    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
    [self.view addSubview:table];


    tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StopWatch.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"TrashCan.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Key.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Telephone.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ChalkBoard.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bucket.png"],nil];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *str = @"TableViewSection";
    return str;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 22;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}

@end
```

I want to have display, this images on the tableview cell.

Please tell me, How to images display on the tableview cell.

My style is only  coding. I use not to storyboard.

Comment: code is ok, what is the issue ?

Comment: Images into NSArray. It's undisplay images on the tableview.I wonder why? :(

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties before the object initialization, try changing the order, like this:

```
table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
table.delegate = self;
table.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

what is your datasource ? xml  tableview cell

this way static
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Maps-icon.png"];
cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Maps-icon.png"];
or

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[newsItem objectForKey:@"image"]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

newsItem NSDictionary

NSDictionary *newsItem = [soapSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];